# IP camera : Set ImageView with byte array data coming from IP camera and download the bitmaps to SD card as images

Tags: ip-camera

We have an custom IP camera and a companion Android service that provides the camera feed as byte[](through socket communication).

```
void onCameraData(byte[] picData)
```

I need to do the following after the method call,

1. Display the byte array data received in an ImageView at Activity.
2. Download the displayed image/bitmap to the SD card.

As the camera feed has 20 FPS, I would like to store maximum 1000 images to SD card. This is to check the image data from IP camera are received correctly in the Application side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Image view with byte array.

   ```
   void setImageViewWithByteData(byte[] picData) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               byte[] data = Arrays.copyOf(picData, picData.length);
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
               if (ivImageView != null){
                   ivImageView.invalidate();
                   ivImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                   downloadFiles(bitmap);
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   }
2. Download the 1000 images to SD card

   ```
     synchronized  void  downloadFiles(Bitmap bmp){
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try{
               if(counter <=1000) {//slip the files after 1000 frames
                   Bitmap bitmap = bmp;
                   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                   OutputStream fOut = null;

                   File file = new File(path, "ipcamera_" + (++counter) + ".jpg"); // the File to save , append increasing numeric counter to prevent files from getting overwritten.
                   fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                   Bitmap pictureBitmap = bitmap; // obtaining the Bitmap
                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG
                   fOut.flush();
                   fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

                   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
                   bitmap.recycle();
                   bitmap = null;
               }
               } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
   }).start();
   ```

   }